# Oracle SQL Total Products By Category

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an exercise that says that I have to do this query: Names of the product categories (CategoryName) and total number of products for each of the categories

I have two tables:
-The first table is called "Categories" where the category of the products is found

-The second table is called "Products" and it contains the products

The primary key "Categoryid" of Categories is shared as a foreign with Products, so I think what to do is count how many products each id has and display the name on the left

I am going to leave two examples with the content of the two tables, since the two tables cannot be joined, but not how to count the number of products for each category

**Table Categories:**

```
| Categoryid | Categoryname ||
| --------  | ------------- ||  
| 1         | Beverages     ||  
| 2         | Condiments    ||
| 3         | Confections   ||
```

**Table Products:**

```
| Productid | Productname   | Categoryid ||
| --------  | ------------- | ---------- ||
| 1         | Chai          |  1         ||
| 2         | Chang         |  1         ||
| 3         | Tofu          |  5         ||
```

**How it should come out:**

```
| CategoryName | TotalProducts||
| --------     | -----------  ||  
| Beverages    | 10           ||  
| Condiments   | 5            ||  
| Confections  | 3            ||
```

I don't know how to count the number of products for each category

i try this:

```
SELECT Categoryname COUNT(*)
FROM Categories  JOIN  Products  ON Categories.Categoryid=Products.Categoryid;
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment (exam, whatever). That is OK, but you must show what you have tried, what worked and what didn't work, what you found difficult or confusing, etc. Just seeing someone else's solution with a trivial join, group by and select count(*) won't help you at all - perhaps it will get your hw done, so what? Still not learning much from it. It will help you a lot more if you try on your onw, then report here what worked and what didn't work.

Comment: It's from an exam that failed, I've been trying different things but I can't get it to work and I wanted to know the answer to practice with other similar exercises since I got stuck in this exercise.

I would like to know even if it is a clue where I can find information on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like outer join (so that you would display categories that don't have any products), counting **products** (not "generally" because you'd get false result; I'll show what I mean).

Sample data (your data is wrong; you can't have Tofu in category 5 if that category doesn't exist; foreign key constraint wouldn't allow it):

```
SQL> with
  2  categories (categoryid, categoryname) as
  3    (select 1, 'beverages'   from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'condiments'  from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'confections' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'category 5'  from dual
  7    ),
  8  products (productid, productname, categoryid) as
  9    (select 1, 'chai' , 1 from dual union all
 10     select 2, 'chang', 1 from dual union all
 11     select 3, 'tofu' , 5 from dual
 12    )
```

Query: count products (line #14):

```
 13  select c.categoryname,
 14         count(p.productid) number_of_products
 15  from categories c left join products p on p.categoryid = c.categoryid
 16  group by c.categoryname;

CATEGORYNAME         NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS
-------------------- ------------------
beverages                             2
category 5                            1
condiments                            0
confections                           0

SQL>
```

---

If you used `count(*)` (line #14), you'd get wrong result as you'd count category itself:

```
 13  select c.categoryname,
 14         count(*) number_of_products
 15  from categories c left join products p on p.categoryid = c.categoryid
 16  group by c.categoryname;

CATEGORYNAME         NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS
-------------------- ------------------
beverages                             2
category 5                            1
condiments                            1     --> no products in
confections                           1     --> these two categories!

SQL>
```

---

However, if you aren't interested in categories that don't have any products, inner join and `count(*)` (as well as `count(p.productid)`) would do:

```
 13  select c.categoryname,
 14         count(*) number_of_products
 15  from categories c join products p on p.categoryid = c.categoryid
 16  group by c.categoryname;

CATEGORYNAME         NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS
-------------------- ------------------
beverages                             2
category 5                            1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation, that's exactly what I was looking for. :)
I would give you +1, but being new does not allow me to vote

Answer (score 0):

For each category I listed all the products and its count.

```
CREATE TABLE categories(  
category_id, category_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Beverages' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Condiments' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Confections' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE products(  
product_id, product_name, category_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'Chai',1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Chang',1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Tofu', 2 FROM DUAL;

select  c.category_id,
        c.category_name,
        listagg(p.product_name,', ') within group(order by p.product_name) product_list,
        count(p.product_name) cnt
  from  categories c,
        products p
  where c.category_id = p.category_id(+)
  group by c.category_id,
           c.category_name
  order by c.category_id,
           c.category_name
/

CATEGORY_ID CATEGORY_NA PRODUCT_LIST                CNT
----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------
          1 Beverages   Chai, Chang                   2
          2 Condiments  Tofu                          1
          3 Confections                               0
```